# Searchable.xml for Android Studio, place where?

Tags: android, xml

Where do you add searchable.xml in Android Studio, under layout, values, where? When adding "new xml file" only have layout or values as options. Any 2014 example code?
Android Studio gives error for this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint" />
```

error: "searchable" element doesn't have required attribute "http:....."

Android Studio does not seem to recognize "`<searchable/>`" as a resource

Answer (score 8):

Rigth click to 'res', 'new android resource file'.
Filename 'searchable.xml', resource type xml, 'ok'.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_label"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint" >
</searchable>
```

On AndroidManifest.xml add next code inside 'application' label.

```
<activity android:name="search.search_class">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>
    </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" <---
                />
</activity>
```

Answer (score 5):

Step by Step Solution :

Step 1 : Right click on **res > New  > Android resource directory**

Step 2 : Popup will open choose **Directory name as *xml*** and **Resource type as *xml***

Step 3 : Then `xml` Directory will be created in `res` folder, Right click on **xml  > New > XML resource file**

Step 4 : popup will open set file name as `searchable.xml` and Root element as `searchable`

`searchable.xml` is created do your code then.

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a folder called **xml** in **res** folder of your android project and place your **searchable.xml** file into **xml** folder

```
`XML file saved at res/xml/searchable.xml:`
```

Do like this below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:hint="@string/search_hint" />
```

In **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable"/> <!-- Your searchable file -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Hope this helps you...

[See this for more info](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/searchable-config.html)